# Oracle: ORA-06550: line 2, column 49: PLS-00363: expression '123dd' cannot be used as an assignment target ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PL/SQL: Statem

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, power-automate, powerapps

I am calling procedure function of ORACLE Database on my POWER AUTOMATE flows

This is params needed to call my procedure function

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GENERATE_INVOICE 
(
    P_PROJECT_PK IN NUMBER 
    , P_USER_ID IN VARCHAR2
    , P_OUTPUT OUT  VARCHAR2
)
```

This is my automate flows

[image]

I think the error is related with IN, OUT, IN OUT types of Oracle Database, but I am not sure How can I design and set variable type on Power Automate. Please help me!

Attached my procedure function

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GENERATE_INVOICE 
(
    P_PROJECT_PK IN NUMBER 
    , P_USER_ID IN VARCHAR2
    , P_OUTPUT OUT  VARCHAR2
) 
AS 
    V_INVOICE_ID            VARCHAR2(100);
    V_INVOICE_LINE_ID       NUMBER;
    V_INVOICE_PK            NUMBER;
    V_INVOICE_DETAIL_PK     NUMBER;
    V_RETVAL                VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
    
    V_INVOICE_LINE_ID := 1;
    
    SELECT TO_CHAR(INVOICE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'FM00000') 
    , INVOICE_PK_SEQ.NEXTVAL
    INTO V_INVOICE_ID, V_INVOICE_PK
    FROM DUAL;
    
    INSERT INTO INVOICE
    SELECT V_INVOICE_PK, C.CLIENT_PK, P_PROJECT_PK, SYSDATE, SYSDATE
    , NVL(P_USER_ID, 'GENERATE_INVOICE') MOD_USER_ID
    , NULL, NULL
    , 0 AMOUNT_PAID
    , 0 AMOUNT_REMAINING
    , C.BILLING_ADDRESS, 
    C.SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
    NULL ACCOUNTING_ADDR,
    NULL BILL_ADDRESSEE,
    SYSDATE INVOICE_CREATE_DATE,
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) + NVL(P.PAYMENT_TERMS,0) DUE_DATE,
    SYSDATE LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
    NULL MEMO,
    NULL MESSAGE,
    P.PO_NUMBER,
    'CREATED' STATUS,
    0 SUBTOTAL,
    NVL(P.PAYMENT_TERMS,0),
    'NET ' || NVL(P.PAYMENT_TERMS,'0') PAYMENT_TERMS_NAME,
    0 TOTAL,
    0 TAX_TOTAL,
    SYSDATE POSTING_DATE,
    NULL NS_ID,
    NULL HR_ID,
    V_INVOICE_ID,
    C.INVOICE_FOOTER_LEFT,
    C.INVOICE_FOOTER_CENTER,
    C.INVOICE_FOOTER_RIGHT,
    NULL
    FROM PROJECT P, CLIENT C
    WHERE P.CLIENT_PK = C.CLIENT_PK
    AND P.PROJECT_PK = P_PROJECT_PK;

    V_RETVAL := 'INVC-' || V_INVOICE_ID;
    
    COMMIT;
    
    P_OUTPUT := V_RETVAL;
  
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    ROLLBACK;
    V_RETVAL := 'ERROR: ' || SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE || ' - ' || SQLERRM,1,1000);
    P_OUTPUT := V_RETVAL;

END GENERATE_INVOICE;
```

Comment: We can't help with the issue with the SQL in the stored procedure, because you didn't post the code for that stored procedure.

Comment: When I run procedure function using sql developer, it worked for me successfully, I think this error is not related with running inner procedure function. Maybe I am wrong, 
Hey @Ken ! Could you please comment for my opinion? Should I share procedure function?

Comment: The error is clearly related to the stored procedure, and the parameters you're passing into it. Without the complete information, we can't help. You're asking us to guess what might be wrong with things you're not showing us, and that's not how SO works.

Comment: I attached procedure function, please help me!

Comment: Well, you provided half of what I asked. What are the exact parameters you're passing into the procedure?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/oracle/#known-issues-and-limitations Out parameters are not currently supported.

Comment: Per the documentation Sam linked to, neither out parameters nor functions are allowed. That means you'll have to do something weird on the database side to get the data out. For example, create a temporary table that only contains data specific to the session, have the stored procedure write data into that temporary table, and then query that temporary table to get the result.